# Writing summation as $A^B$, where have to find $A$ and $B$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Write $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1000} \binom{1000}{k}5^k$ as $A^B$, where have to find $A$ and $B$.

I would love to tell you what I've tried, but I don't even understand the question, so have no idea where to begin. I know I could write $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1000} \binom{1000}{k}$ as $2^{1000}$, but I don't see how that helps. Feeling pretty stupid :(

Comment: Just take $A = \sum_{k=0}^{1000} \binom{1000}{k}5^k$ and $B = 1$.

Comment: All silliness aside, are you familiar with the binomial theorem?

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes, that is what we've been studying

Comment: Does the expression you've been given look like one side of the equation in the binomial theorem? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I don't understand this $A$ and $B$ thing tho? How can I express that as some sort of variable we have to find?

Comment: You are free to choose $A, B$, which is why I made my original (joking) comment. The point is to find very simple numbers $A, B$ such that $A^B = \sum_{k=0}^{1000} \binom{1000}{k} 5^k$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I was thinking we had to write it as $A^B$ literally somehow. Sigh. Im dumb. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $(1+5)^{1000}$.  Binomial theorem !

Comment: Thank you very much. I see it now.